# MySQL - change and copy data from one database to another

Tags: mysql

I have one databse with many tables. Each table has multiple float type columns and milions rows.

I need to copy all data to second database and "convert" columns with some formula (usually something like `new_val = (int)(old_val * 10)`) or condition (`IF old_val IS NULL new_val = 9999`).

What is the best way (performance-wise) to do this?

Comment: Are the databases on the same server or different servers?

Comment: @Barmar Same server

Comment: If so simply copy data using `INSERT .. SELECT` query.

Comment: Right. `INSERT INTO newdb.table (col1, col2, col3, ...) SELECT old_col1 * 100, ... FROM olddb.table`